# How can I implement --ignore-matching-lines in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Git diff has a nice option --ignore-matching-lines, which allows to hide lines matching certain regex. E.g. the following command hides all files where only imports block changed.

```
git diff -I 'import *' master...mybranch
```

This is super helpful to keep only meaningful changes in PRs. Is there a way to configure the same thing in Bitbucket?

Thank you